# Why Motion Animation is not working in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I am using [Motion](https://cosmicmind.gitbook.io/motion/) library from CosmicMind to add animations in my app. I tried as the documentation said. Though documentation has a different syntax. But I changed it to as it should be according to current swift syntax. But it's not working.

```
let animatations: [MotionAnimation] = [.delay(1), .duration(5), .background(color: .red), .border(color: .purple)]
                    cell.button.animate(animatations, completion: {

                    })
```

Here button is a UIButton in my custom UITableViewCell. No animation worked.

Comment: what did you try so far? animation outside of cell are working? is anything working?

Comment: Everything is working as it should other than the animation

Comment: so animations are not working at all? not even a single one in the app?

Comment: I think it is not working for view items that are created inside xib files